# Mod_security - help needed

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, mod-security

I need help configuring mod_security. I installed the component in joomla CMS. One function does not work. I think it's the fault of configuring mod_security. However, I can't handle the configuration.
Can anyone suggest me how to configure mod_security so that the following error does not appear?

Thank you for any suggestions
greetings

Mariusz

```
--70c75e19-H--
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1576492965429719 55389 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1576492965429719 55389; combined=3, p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=3, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9.
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips

--70c75e19-Z--

--f4ebab2d-A--
[16/Dec/2019:11:43:18 +0100] Xfdfxt4HssQCZkLHjRnp17QAAAAA 192.168.11.19 54334 222.222.222.222 443
--f4ebab2d-B--
POST /administrator/index.php?option=**com_arismartbook**&task=ajaxOrderUp&categoryId=16 HTTP/1.1
Host: test2.tld.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 119
Origin: https://test2.tld.pl
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://test2.tld.pl/administrator/index.php?option=com_arismartbook&view=categories
Cookie: wf_browser_dir=eczasopisma/Akcent/Rok_2014/nr1; cookieconsent_status=dismiss; e8c44a98a762cac37a9dc36fe9daa126=pl0h5nbstk465jhgoohn1kc5m9; joomla_user_state=logged_in; b00894f58bebfc7f2swE6f509b1869a6=dvkignad5f8r2fn9mkt1v5kca6

--f4ebab2d-F--
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.25
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

--f4ebab2d-H--
Apache-Handler: application/x-httpd-php
Stopwatch: 1576492998778551 50173 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1576492998778551 50173; combined=3, p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=3, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.2 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); OWASP_CRS/2.2.9.
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips

--f4ebab2d-Z--
```

Comment: Unofrtunately there's no detail in that extract explaining what the actual error is. Based on that, ModSecurity does not appear to have blocked this. Check your PHP logs and/or Apache error logs to see if they give any further clues.

Comment: I've put the following options in my vhost. I restarted httpd but I don't see any messages in the logs. Did I miss something?

php_flag log_errors On
php_value error_log /var/log/php.log

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have already managed it

Comment: Would you either please close your question (if it turned out to be something simple) or answer it (you can accept your own answer).